# L'utilisation de « du » dans « pas du tout »

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation, locutions

Je sais que la traduction de « not at all » est « pas du tout », mais pourquoi « du » et pas « de » ?

J'ai pensé qu'en général le mot « pas » est suivi de « de », comme « je n'ai pas de voiture », ou « pas de problème ».

Ma question est pourquoi « du », et est-ce qu'il y a plusieurs exemples de l'utilisation d'un partitif à la place d'un « de » de négation ?

Comment: Note that you can also say something like: *je n'ai pas de voiture du tout*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *pas du tout*, the *de* that is contained in *du* is a preposition. It plays more or less the same role the *at* plays in the English locution.

Since this *de* isn't an article, the rule you know about articles in negative sentences doesn't apply here.

Comment: It is still mysterious how *pas de le tout* means *not at all*.

Comment: @GAMPUB Réponse dans le TLFi.

Answer (score 7):

On ne peut pas traduire *not at all* par « pas de tout » car cette dernière expression signifie *not of everything*.

Les deux formes ne sont pas interchangeables, on dit

> Je **n'en** veux pas [du tout] = Je ne veux rien.

mais

> Je **ne** veux pas de tout = J'en veux une partie.

Dans la première phrase, « du tout » est optionnel. Il sert juste à renforcer le « pas » tandis que dans le deuxième exemple, « de tout » est indispensable pour préserver le sens de la phrase.

« Du tout » signifie « complètement, absolument » mais il n'est plus employé dans ce sens positif. Associé à une forme négative comme dans « pas du tout » ou « rien du tout », il accentue la négation. Voir [TOUT<sup>3</sup>, subst. masc. B](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout/2).

---

You can't translate "not at all" by *pas de tout* because the latter means "not of everything".

Both forms can't be swapped, we say

> Je **n'en** veux pas [du tout] = I want nothing of it/I don't want anything of it.

but

> Je **ne** veux pas de tout = I don't want all of it, i.e. I want some of it.

In the first sentence, *du tout* is optional and is used to reinforce the *pas* while in the second one, *de tout* is mandatory to preserve the sentence meaning.

*Du tout* means « completely, absolutely » but is no more used with this positive acceptation. Appended to a negative form like *pas du tout* or *rien du tout*, it accentuates the negation. See [TOUT<sup>3</sup>, subst. masc. B](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout/2).

Comment: Merci pour le lien vers le TLFi. C'est encore un peu mystérieux même avec la référence à cause de la portée respective de la négation et de *du tout*. En pratique, cela signifie *absolument pas* plutôt que *pas absolument*.

Answer (score -2):

De manière générale, le mot "du" est une contraction de "de le".

Comment: *Du* is the contraction of *de le* only. *De la* does not contract.

Comment: And of course you're right :P

Comment: Cette réponse ne répond pas de le tout à la question posée.