# What is the difference between “du” and “de”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

I am struggling with figuring out the difference between when to use *de* and *du*.

Can someone explain to me what these mean, and when I would use them.

Comment: "Du" means "de le", voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/quand-utiliser-de-le-au-lieu-de-du http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/why-je-viens-de-lacheter-even-if-we-have-just-bought-un-livre http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/quand-du-et-quand-de http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/lutilisation-de-du-dans-pas-du-tout